# Change the colors of an SVG fill pattern from CSS

Tags: css, svg

Ok, so I've got two shapes, and they're both filled with a pattern of blue polka dots on a yellow background as defined by an svg pattern.  Works fine.

But, say I want to use the same pattern and have the second shape show it in different colors, without defining a second pattern?  In my actual project I have dozens of items that I want to share the same pattern, but with many different potential colors.  Is there a way to change the colors outside of the pattern def, maybe with CSS?

```
<style>
.pattern-dots .base{
  fill: url(#pattern-dots);}
</style>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="313.405px" height="145.757px" viewBox="0 0 313.405 145.757" enable-background="new 0 0 313.405 145.757"
     xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_1" class="pattern-dots">
    <path class="base" d="M47.865,56.567l37.838-16.216L128.271,64c0,0-29.73,8.783-20.946,29.729
        C107.324,93.729,44.486,91.027,47.865,56.567z"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_2" class="pattern-dots">
    <path class="base" d="M213.133,29.609c5.319,1.958,7.124,9.153,11,13.511c6.386,7.18,12.748,3.645,21.301,6.196
        c16.13,4.812,26.723,18.663,19.742,35.545c-4.383,10.6-19.383,18.412-30.038,19.78c-4.478,0.574-15.175,1.553-18.654-1.476
        c-4.315-3.756-1.739-11.636-5.343-15.463c-4.807-5.105-19.233-2.016-26.201-2.016c-11.164,0-18.879,2.396-20.469-10.672
        c-0.763-6.275,0.461-12.744,4.951-17.417c4.568-4.754,12.449-3.735,16.486-7.954c4.264-4.456,1.923-11.502,7.646-16.036
        C198.242,29.894,207.393,27.497,213.133,29.609z"/>
</g>
</svg>

<svg id='pattern' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
<pattern id="pattern-dots" width="50" height="50" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<rect x="-0.506" fill="#ffe2b4" width="51.107" height="50" class="background"/>
<path fill="#999BC5" d="M15.946,12.651c0,1.905-1.544,3.45-3.45,3.45c-0.953,0-1.815-0.386-2.439-1.011
    c-0.624-0.624-1.01-1.486-1.01-2.439c0-1.905,1.544-3.45,3.45-3.45S15.946,10.746,15.946,12.651z"/>
<path fill="#999BC5" d="M38.945,35.65c0,1.906-1.544,3.45-3.449,3.45c-1.322,0-2.471-0.743-3.049-1.835
    c-0.256-0.481-0.4-1.031-0.4-1.615c0-1.904,1.544-3.449,3.449-3.449S38.945,33.746,38.945,35.65z"/></pattern>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Here's the jsfiddle, showing the two shapes with matching fills.

https://jsfiddle.net/pzzbncty/

Comment: No, that's the point of a `def`. At best you could define the pattern **without** colors and see if you can apply them afterwards....but I doubt that would work...but you can try.

Comment: If I target them after they'd still be pointed at the def, which would result in all the objects on the page taking on the same colors...at least that's what's happening now.  That's why I'm looking for a separate way to change the colors.  I'm open to other suggestions.  Basically I'm working on a paper doll program, and want to be able to add colored patterns over whatever color is already inside a shape.  I just haven't figured out a better way to do that.

Comment: As I said, you can create the `def` **without** the fill colors (i.e. just the paths) and try and apply them to the SVG somehow afterwards...but I'm pretty sure it won't work. I'm afraid you may have to re-think your methodology.

Comment: @Paulie_D If you did that (which you can do) all shapes with that pattern would update to use those colours.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought.